# mcheck.h is missing in windows but not linux

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, cygwin, mingw

I have been trying to run a code which needs a library called

```
#include <mcheck.h>
```

Apparently this library is part of gnulib:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mcheck.3.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/mcheck_002eh.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace

So I expect this to be inside gcc. So I created a simple code as following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mcheck.h>
int main()
{
    printf("salam");
}
```

And I run in different environments. In linux, it is working fine, but I am not able to make in Windows with whatever tricks I used. **So dies gcc in Windows contain this library?**

Here is an image of making it with gcc. The gcc version is: 
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)

[image]

Here is a failure in cygwin, with gcc version: gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
[image]

Failure CodeBlocks with internal GNU gcc compiler 
[image]

Failure with Visual Studio 2012: 
[image]

Failure with MinGW with gcc version 4.8.1: 
[image]

Comment: btw, any ideas for better title?

Comment: I don't know about all that Windows stuff but I know that gnulib is not part of GCC.  You are supposed to add (preferably using `gnulib-tool`) those parts of gnulib you want to use to your project.  Unless one of these Windows ports decided to include all of gnulib into their standard include and library path.

Answer (score 4):

This header is GNU-specific, it doesn't exist on Windows. Implementing its functionality in Windows would be difficult as this would require hooks into the malloc() implementation that comes with the visual studio compiler.

Fortunately, this doesn't matter. As all these functions do is consistency checking you can simply add stubs to your project that do nothing and always report success.

```
/* mcheck.h */
#ifndef __MCHECK_H
#define __MCHECK_H

enum mcheck_status
{
  MCHECK_DISABLED, MCHECK_OK, MCHECK_FREE, MCHECK_HEAD, MCHECK_TAIL
};

int mcheck (void (*abortfunc)(enum mcheck_status mstatus));
int mcheck_pedantic (void (*abortfunc)(enum mcheck_status mstatus));
void mcheck_check_all ();
enum mcheck_status mprobe (void *ptr);

#endif
```

---

```
/* mcheck.c */
#include "mcheck.h"

int mcheck (void (*abortfunc)(enum mcheck_status mstatus))
{
    return 0;
}

int mcheck_pedantic (void (*abortfunc)(enum mcheck_status mstatus))
{
    return 0;
}

void mcheck_check_all ()
{
}

enum mcheck_status mprobe (void *ptr)
{
    return MCHECK_OK;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted, @Daniel